# How do I prevent UITableView separator color from turning black in UIPopoverController (iOS7)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uipopovercontroller

My app uses a UITableViewController, which is a child of UINavigationController, which is the content view controller of a UIPopoverController.  I am customizing the appearance of the UITableView of the UITableViewController.  It works perfectly for iOS 5 and 6, but it has an issue in iOS7.  The separators of the cells are set to be white in color, and the table view initially appears with the correct separator color.  However, once I scroll the table view and the cells are reloaded (meaning cellForRowAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell functions are called), the separators of the newly reloaded cells are all black.

I am customizing the separator color by calling this function in the UITableViewController's viewDidLoad function:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

If I use the exact same table view elsewhere in the app (not in a UIPopoverController), then I do not have this problem.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in the documentation to indicate that this should work differently for iOS 7 than for 5 or 6.  Maybe it's an iOS bug?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you planing to remove the table separator or your table is dark? by the way there is a lot of glitches like this in iOS7.

Comment: The table view cells are colored, so the separators are visible when white.  So I don't want them removed.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem with a table view inside a popover on the iPad. The cause seems to be due to reloading the table view before it appears - if I don't do that, and instead reload it once it has been added to the screen, it works slightly better.

Comment: I have not been able to figure out any solution on this since I ran into the problem, and it certainly looks like an iOS7 UIKit bug.  I've filed the bug with Apple but have not heard anything back yet.

Comment: Having the same issue. Tried calling setSeparatorColor() in the ViewController's viewWillAppear method(), and here setSeparatorColor() has NO effect the 2nd and nth time it's called. Only the first. Looks like a bug indeed. Thanks for filing with Apple.

Comment: Please let us know when you hear back from Apple. Thanks.

Comment: try setting it to clear color
Another method :- set seperator style of tableview = none.

Comment: @user1021430 Reloading the table data in viewDidAppear seems to salvage the situation for me.

Comment: @zambrey could you elaborate on this solution? I tried that and saw no improvement...

Comment: @TimWindsorBrown I did that because I read up somewhere that reloading rows in table made separators reappear and also I could see separators reappearing if I forced UITableViewCell to reload by scrolling it off-screen.

Comment: I uploaded an example project to Apple for this and haven't heard back about it.  As I recall, calling reloadData on the table view in the table view controller's viewDidAppear doesn't change anything, though I haven't looked at it in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was an iOS bug - the issue no longer occurs for me for iOS7.0.4.  I do not know exactly which version it was fixed in.  So there's no need to reloadData or set separatorColor in viewWillAppear.  It's sufficient to do this in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

set this in `viewwillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Exact solution is mentioned in Vern Jensen's comment. Doesn't seem to work for all.

Answer (score 1):

This iOS bug still occurs in iOS7.0.6. I had a table with black background and white separator lines. The separator lines displayed correctly in white on first view of the `UIPopover`, but appeared black on the second and subsequent displays of the same popover.

Using reloadData on the tableview didn't help.

The only practical workaround I could find was the following, which causes the entire table to be redrawn:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Notes

1) If you use only the `viewWillAppear` code, then the separator lines appear correctly for an instant before going black again. If you use only the `viewDidAppear` code, then there is a noticeable delay before the separator lines turn white, after the popover is displayed. Using BOTH provides the most visually seamless result for the user.

2) If your table has more than one section, then you should ensure all sections are reloaded, because the user may have scrolled to another section before the popover was hidden.

PS - After further testing, I found that even this solution is not perfect. After redisplay, if you scroll the table,  separators that were initially offscreen revert to black again. Hence it works correctly only if the table doesn't have enough rows to go beyond the size of the popover.

Answer (score 0):

Two recommendations:
1. Don't use `UITableViewController` at all. The automated behaviour it provides can be easily implemented with a few calls and also it breaks the good `OOP` practices.
2. About the separators, don't show separators, but add a `UIView` in each cell at the bottom with width equal to the cell's width and height of 1 point.